# make a URL short

Tags: url

I am developing a site on localhost WAMP server. I have a confidential page to show up before index.php is shown. Below is my confidentiality.php code:

```
<?php
$body ="";
$body .= "
<p>
    By clicking on the Enter button below to access......
</p>
<form action='http://hello.com' method='GET'>
    <input type='submit' value='Enter'/>
</form>";
echo $body;
?>
```

The problem is, I don't want my clients to enter the following long address on the address bar, instead I want them to enter something simple like localhost and then they will be directed to the following url.

http://hello.com:8080/clean-url-project/confidentiality%20.php

I am trying to make it   http://hello.com.     So that the port and all the other info will not be entered.

I tried some of the clean url methods but no success. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

WAMP server and most default apache configurations will server index.php from the directory root, so if you use this as index.php it should solve your problem.

Comment: Can you describe it to me briefly.

Comment: Ok. It is not actually on a localhost server, I have edited the question. Can you look it up again.

Comment: All I'm suggesting is putting this page in the root directory of your site as index.php. The webserver will serve this when they go to hello.com, which seems to be the goal.

Comment: thank you for your responses, how can I avoid the port number?

Comment: You won't need the port number if you're using the standard http port 80. If not, you can forward port 80 from your router to whatever your webserver is set at, or you can do some fancy firewall configuration (outside my knowledge). Why is your production webserver on 8080? You could implement a kind of 'dirty' solution by running another lightweight web server (nginx,lighttp,etc) on port 80 and simply redirect to the port your real server is on.